# Куда поместить логику вызова серверных скриптов - в php на сервере или в JS на клиенте?

Tags: php, javascript, mvc, архитектура, структуры

Приложение построено на MVC.

Модель храниться в скриптах на сервере.

За Представление отвечают JS-скрипты. Они строят HTML на основании информации, которую извлекает Контроллер. Так же отслеживают действия Пользователя и говорят Контроллеру, что ещё нужно вытащить с сервера.

Контроллер - JS-скрипт, который в зависимости от задачи вызывает различные php-скрипты на сервере.

Сейчас JS-контроллер делает это напрямую.

*Сомнение - а не плохо ли, что можно открыть JS и посмотреть какие скрипты на сервере задействованы в той или иной ситуации?*

*Является ли это вообще хорошей практикой?*

Вопрос - оставить как есть, чтобы логика какие серверные скрипты вызывать была на клиенте?

Или лучше перенести её на сервер - все запросы проводить через один php-файл с длиннющим блоком if...else, который в зависимости от содержания запроса будет вызывать нужный скрипт? А JS-Контроллер сделать файлом, через который централизованно происходит обращение к серверу?

Answer (score 1):

> Контроллер - JS-скрипт, который в зависимости от задачи вызывает различные php-скрипты на сервере.

Вызывать различные php скрипты на сервере - уже давно является плохой практикой. Современные MVC приложения имеют единую точку входа. Посмотрите на популярные MVC фреймворки - Laravel, Symfony, Yii2 и т.д. Все они используют роутинг.

Если не используете фреймворки, посмотрите в сторону маленькой библиотеки [`bramus/router`](https://github.com/bramus/router). Библиотека устанавливается через composer.

Но если вы не используете composer в своих проектах (я в 2018 встречал программистов со стажем, которые сидят в php 5.3 (это жесть!)), то очень рекомендую сначала закрыть пробелы в основах автозагрузки классов и управления зависимостями.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А современные шаблоны фронтенд, Flux, в частности не подразумевает запросы к backend напрямую(без роутера) из скрипта контролирующего состояние/данные?

Comment: С композитором хорошо знаком))) За библитеку спасибо, но у меня есть свой роутер)))

Comment: Не вижу никакой проблемы)) Делаю CPA на Vue + Laravel. Очень выразительно получается. В laravel абстракция `Request` (Symfony компонент) имеет полезные методы, в частности `ajax()`. При гет запросе страницы отдаю отрендеренный в ноде html (ssr), при ajax запросе этого же роута (переход на клиентском роутинге) отдаю json необходимых данных, которые записываю в state, а оттуда уже все необходимые vue компоненты берут данные для себя. Главное выдавать initial state при обычном запросе

Comment: Vue, экзотика))) А почему нельзя просто отправить голый html с подключеным Vue <script>? А он сам уже всё построит как нужно - судя по документации https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html Есть такая возможность? Спасибо в любом случае!

Comment: смысла нет рендерить всю страницу. Во время захода рендерится вся разметка, влючая меню, каталог и т.п. Эти данные берутся из бд. А при ajax запросе берутся только контекстные данные, относящиеся только к текущей странице.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что во время захода рендеринг происходит на сервере средствами Laravel? Далее страницу меняет Vue? И последний вопрос... При каком-то действии меняется вся страница полностью, например, вместо личного кабинета - вывод статистики игроков. Можно отрендерить страницу на сервере и передать её код по Ajax. А можно поменять всё силами Vue. Какая практика лучше в этом случае?

Comment: В Laravel вся бизнес логика, работа с БД, интеграции с сервисами. параллельно работает node.js сервер, к которому обращается laravel за отрендеренным html. Нода в данном случае делает самую тупую работу - рендерит. Чтобы полностью страницу поменять, достаточно переадресовать на нужный URI